# MS Dynamics AX / AXAPTA - Where is the code that prevents reprint of payment advices of unposted cheques?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

We want to reprint a payment advice, even before it is posted. The report 
BankPaymAdviceCheque should be able to do this but only prints advices for 
already posted cheques. The report's dialog, however, allows you to choose 
unposted ones as well.

No matter how I searched in the code, I cannot find 
the bit that prevents unposted remittances from being re-printed -

Help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is in the vendTransInvoice method. When the report is run for a check that has already printed and posted, vendOutPaymCheque will be null, so the block of code that looks up records in vendTrans and vendSettlement gets run. When the report is run during the printing of a check, vendOutPaymCheque isn't null, so the block of code that looks up records in specTrans gets run. When the report is called for a check that has printed but not posted, this code is incorrectly looking up records in vendTrans and vendSettlement and not finding any data because the journal hasn't posted yet.